# ionic capacitor run android throws an error

Tags: java, android, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am trying to run my Ionic app on a Android virtual device with capacitor, however i am having issues when running this command.

Command:

```
ionic capacitor run android
```

I get the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
[capacitor] > Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @10f1863c
```

I am unsure what this means. Ios runs find, but android throws this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That’s a Java 16 bug, use java 11

Comment: thank you - uninstalled java 16 and used 11 instead.